# How to compute the "true test mean square error"?

Tags: cross-validation, mse

In page 182 of *An Introduction To Statistical Learning*, author wrote this:

> When we examine real data, we do not know the true test MSE, and so it
> is difficult to determine the accuracy of the cross-validation
> estimate. However, if we examine simulated data, then we can compute
> the true test MSE, and can thereby evaluate the accuracy of our
> cross-validation results.

I don't know what the true test MSE is and I can't find any information on it. What is the calculation formula of it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing else than test MSE calculated on test dataset (equation 2.6 in the book).

The authors use this term (specifically, putting *true* in front of the test MSE) in order to clearly make the distinction between the MSE calculated on the test dataset and the estimated test MSE that is obtained via cross-validation.

You can have a look at Figures 2.9-2.11: test MSEs which are shown in red there is the same as the "true" test MSEs from Figure 5.6 shown in blue.